# react and php form validation empty fields error comes up even if the fields aren't empty

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate the information and so I check whether any of the fields are empty, but even when the fields are filled the error "Need to complete all the fields" gets set off. This doesn't make sense, because it still registers the user and the data is in the database, which means that actually those variables in the $array aren't undedined. So I'm having a really tough time understanding why this error is set off.

This is my post request.

```
const registerUser = async (userData) => {
     
    console.log(userData)
  
    const request = await fetch("http://localhost/practise-api/public/users/registerUser",{
      method:"POST",
      headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: userData.firstname,
        email: userData.email,
        password: userData.password,
        secondname: userData.secondname
      })
    })
  
    let res = await request.text()
    console.log(res)
    
    if(res.status === "fail"){
      setShowModal(true)
    }
    else if(res.status === "success"){
      setSuccess(true);
    }
    
  }
```

This is where I validate the data and then register the user.

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


class Users extends BaseController
{

    public function registerUser()
    {

        $array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        $this->response->setContentType('Content-Type: application/json');
        if(!isset($array["email"]) || !isset($array["password"]) || !isset($array["secondname"]) || !isset($array["firstname"])){
            $error = array(
                'msg' => 'Need to complete all the fields',
                'status' => 'fail'
            );
            return json_encode($error);
        }
        elseif(!filter_var($array["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )){
            $error = array(
                'msg' => 'Invalid email',
                'status' => 'fail'
            );
            return json_encode($error);
        }
        elseif(!strlen($array["password"]) >= 8){
            $error = array(
                'msg' => 'Password is too short',
                'status' => 'fail'
            );
            return json_encode($error);
        }
        $email = $array["email"];
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table("users");
        $builder->select("*");
        $builder->where("email", $email);
        $queryResult = $builder->get()->getResultArray();
        if($queryResult){
            $error = array(
                'msg' => 'User already exists',
                'status' => 'fail'
            );
            return json_encode($error);
        }
        else{
            $firstname = $array["firstname"];
            $secondname = $array["secondname"];
            $password = $array["password"];
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $userData = [
                "firstname" => $firstname,
                "lastname" => $secondname,
                "email" => $email,
                "password" => $hashedPassword
            ];
            $builder->insert($userData);
            $success = array(
                'msg' => 'You created an account successfully',
                'status' => 'success'
            );
            return json_encode($success);
            
        }
        

        
        // print_r("hello");
        // echo json_encode($array);
        // echo json_encode($email);
    }
}
```

[image: As you can see here it sets off the empty fields error, but also the account is registered]

Hope someone can help me, thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible for it to return `Need to complete all the fields` _and_ move on to the insert in the same request. Double check that you don't do more than one request (where one is missing info.) Check the network tab in the browsers dev-tools when you make the request to check what calls are made. Then you can also check what data it sends and what the response really is.

Comment: In that picture like it shows that it sets off the error, but the account also gets registered, so I'm so confused and okay thank you I'll check the network tab

Comment: I checked the network tab and the data that's being sent looks fine. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$array` right after decoding the input to see what it actually contains?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I misunderstood the question. I second what Magnus said, there have to be multiple requests.